# How to extract portion of string before first number in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, string, substring

I am trying to split a string and want to get everything before the first number in the string. I've tried using this:

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(table.column, Number, 1)
```

But I'm not sure what needs to go where "Number" is. I know I can specify a character but how do I specify the first number?

The data looks like:

```
Azura Power West Africa Ltd 100% (Edo State Government 2.5%, Azura Edo Ltd 97.5%)
```

In the end, I want it to be just

```
Azura Power West Africa Ltd
```

Comment: can you provide sample data

Answer (score 1):

`LEFT(table.column, (REGEXP_INSTR(table.column, '[0-9]')-1))`

This gets everything to the left of the first number. In your case you might need to replace -1 with -2 to remove the space before the number as well.